# Como pasar o devolver una variable de .VBS llamado desde .BAT

Tags: cmd, vbscript

Tengo un script en cmd que llama a un script de vbs, el cual ejecuta una serie de operaciones y genera un array que me interesa poder devolver al script de cmd, me preguntaba si esto es posible y de ser así, como podría hacerlo.

El método que estoy usando para llamar al .vbs desde el .bat es el comando CALL.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final solucione el problema imprimiendo todo el contenido del array en un archivo de texto, leyendo posteriormente el contenido del mismo desde el script de cmd y borrandolo finalmente, no es exactamente lo que buscaba pero de momento me ha servido esta solución.